# Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.x.yyy'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to connect to the database remotely.

I changed the mysqld.cnf to

```
  [mysqld]
  bind-address      = 192.168.x.yyy
  mysqlx-bind-address   = 192.168.x.yyy
  skip-networking
```

I checked the ports with iptables -S

```
   -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -c 10 600 -j ACCEPT
   -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -c 0 0 -j ACCEPT
```

I tried to run telnet 192.168.x.yyy 3306

```
   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Of course, I called

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

The command mysql -u root -p is OK but  mysql -h 192.168.x.yyy -u root -p returns

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.x.yyy' (111)
```

The table mysql.user contains:

```
mysql> select Host,User from user;

 +---------------+------------------+
 | Host          | User             |
 +---------------+------------------+
 | 192.168.x.yyy | root             |
 | ...
 | localhost     | root             |
 +---------------+------------------+
```

The ifconfig returns:

```
enp2s0f0: ...
   inet 192.168.x.yyy  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.x.255
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and mysqld 8.0.23

Answer (score 0):

In your quoted `mysqld.cnf`, you have included the `skip-networking` rule which disabled all external network access to the MySQL server.

If remote access is required, you should remove this rule and restart your mysql server process.

See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_networking) for further details.

Comment: Thanks Holger. Now, it is working fine with the command